# Line breaks in code within print statement causing spaces in values printed to screen

Tags: python, scrapy

I have some code that is printing items from a list with no spaces between each item and a comma separating them:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
import re
import json

class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "goal4"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com"]
    download_delay = 1

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(''),deny=('/News', '/Fixtures', '/Graphics', '/Articles', '/Live', '/Matches', '/Explanations', '/Glossary', '/Players', 'ContactUs', 'TermsOfUse'),), follow=False, callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)

        match1 = re.search(re.escape("DataStore.prime('stage-player-stat', defaultTeamPlayerStatsConfigParams.defaultParams , ") \
                     + '(\[.*\])' + re.escape(");"), response.body)

        if match1 is not None:
            playerdata1 = match1.group(1)

            for player in json.loads(playerdata1):

                print ("{TeamId},{PlayerId},{Name},{FirstName},{LastName},{TeamName},{PositionText},{PositionLong} \
            ,{Age} \
            ,{Height},{Weight},{GameStarted},{SubOn},{SubOff} \
            ,{Goals},{OwnGoals},{Assists},{Yellow},{SecondYellow},{Red} \
            ,{TotalShots} \
            ,{ShotsOnTarget},{ShotsBlocked},{TotalPasses},{AccuratePasses},{KeyPasses} \
            ,{TotalLongBalls},{AccurateLongBalls},{TotalThroughBalls},{AccurateThroughBalls} \
            ,{AerialWon},{AerialLost},{TotalTackles},{Interceptions},{Fouls} \
            ,{Offsides},{OffsidesWon},{TotalClearances},{WasDribbled},{Dribbles} \
            ,{WasFouled} \
            ,{Dispossesed},{Turnovers},{TotalCrosses},{AccurateCrosses}".decode().format(**player))
```

This works fine for the elements in the list up until the first line break. This is meant to represent a line break in the code, not any break on screen. All elements directly after the break are printed with a huge space between it and the previous element. Those that are between break print fine, until the next break etc.

What I would like to know is, how can I break this code up onto multiple lines without it effecting how the print is displayed?

Thanks

Comment: Alternatively to enrico.bacis' answer you could simply drop the indentation within the code. But you'd sacrifice code readability, which is usually not what you want. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a very long string in a pythonic way, instead of this:

```
s = 'this string is soooo\
     ooo loooong'
```

Which, because of the leading spaces in the second line, prints as:

```
this string is soooo       ooo loooong
```

You can use:

```
s = ('this string is soooo'
     'ooo loooong')
```

Which prints as:

```
this string is sooooooo long
```

In your case you should have:

```
print ('{TeamId},{PlayerId},{Name},{FirstName},{LastName},{TeamName},{PositionText},{PositionLong}'
       ',{Age}'
       ...
       ',{Dispossesed},{Turnovers},{TotalCrosses},{AccurateCrosses}').decode().format(**player)
```

Comment: bacis hi, thanks for replying. in my above example, if i remove the line breaks, python stops recognising my statement as one continuous string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"""` triple quotes and `replace`:

```
print ("""{TeamId},{PlayerId},{Name},{FirstName},{LastName},{TeamName},{PositionText},{PositionLong} 
                ,{Age} 
                ,{Height},{Weight},{GameStarted},{SubOn},{SubOff} 
                ,{Goals},{OwnGoals},{Assists},{Yellow},{SecondYellow},{Red} 
                ,{TotalShots} 
                ,{ShotsOnTarget},{ShotsBlocked},{TotalPasses},{AccuratePasses},{KeyPasses} 
                ,{TotalLongBalls},{AccurateLongBalls},{TotalThroughBalls},{AccurateThroughBalls} 
                ,{AerialWon},{AerialLost},{TotalTackles},{Interceptions},{Fouls} 
                ,{Offsides},{OffsidesWon},{TotalClearances},{WasDribbled},{Dribbles} 
                ,{WasFouled} 
                ,{Dispossesed},{Turnovers},{TotalCrosses},{AccurateCrosses}""".replace(" ","").decode().format(**player))
```

Or in your own code:

```
print ("{TeamId},{PlayerId},{Name},{FirstName},{LastName},{TeamName},{PositionText},{PositionLong} \
            ,{Age} \
            ,{Height},{Weight},{GameStarted},{SubOn},{SubOff} \
            ,{Goals},{OwnGoals},{Assists},{Yellow},{SecondYellow},{Red} \
            ,{TotalShots} \
            ,{ShotsOnTarget},{ShotsBlocked},{TotalPasses},{AccuratePasses},{KeyPasses} \
            ,{TotalLongBalls},{AccurateLongBalls},{TotalThroughBalls},{AccurateThroughBalls} \
            ,{AerialWon},{AerialLost},{TotalTackles},{Interceptions},{Fouls} \
            ,{Offsides},{OffsidesWon},{TotalClearances},{WasDribbled},{Dribbles} \
            ,{WasFouled} \
            ,{Dispossesed},{Turnovers},{TotalCrosses},{AccurateCrosses}".replace(" ","").decode().format(**player))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply break the string up into pieces and then concatenate them with the plus sign. e.g. 'Hello ' + 'World'